# Duplicate items in array from SOAP

Tags: soap, array, order-duplication

Im trying to get a list of items from an order to display correctly on my webpage using the SOAP API. I have managed to display shipping, billing and general info, and i have also managed to display the list of items... BUT for some reason i am getting duplicate results with a price and row_total equaling zero, the picture below shows what i mean:

[image: items_display]

So as you can see there are 2 records for ink_med and 2 for coal_sm, but only 1 record for the last entry.

My question to you guys is, how do i stop the duplicate records?

Here is the call im using to retrieve the order items:

```
$sales_order_info = $this->client->salesOrderInfo($this->sessionID,$o->increment_id);
```

And i access the items array by using this:

```
foreach($sales_order_info->items as $i)
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the items are configurables, and you will get both the configurable and the corresponding simple product in your collection. The simple items that belong to a confirable will have the `parent_id` (where this is the item_id of the configurable). This way you can filter out the duplicate items and only show the items you want.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, so will it be better to show the configurable or the simple product? Thanks

Comment: I have just looked on the back end of magento, and the products are simple...not configurable? Im using magentos sample data by the way

Comment: The ink_med shirt is a simple product that is a child product of the sku 'ink' and that is a configurable product. Looking at the sales_order/view template Magento displays only the parent items (it skips the rows where the item has a parent item, this is also the records where the price is available.

Comment: Oh i see now. Ok so what is the best way to filter out the simple from the configurable? I also dont understand what you mean with your last sentence? Do you mean i should therefore just list the simple products? Thanks

Comment: You should just list the configurable items, if you check the array you can skip all the records that have the parent_id setup

Comment: But what if i have simple products that have been brought too? like the nokia phone is a simple product and still needs to be shown? thanks

Comment: I also can not see parent_id in the  salesOrderItemEntity array of sales_order_info call?

Answer (score 1):

What Vladimir Kerkhoff has written is right. You get both the configurable product and also the corresponding simple product.

But i want to add, in Magento 1.9.2, maybe earlier, there is no parent_id in the soap api available. So his solution did not work for me.

I had to extend the api. Fortunately this is quite easy. Create a barebones extension and add a file wsdl.xml to the etc-folder of this extension.

Paste the following into this File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />

            <complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="parent_item_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

parent_item_id is your key for the soap api then.

Comment: Had to clear magento cache (var/cache folder) for extra field to appear

Answer (score 0):

Using the SOAP api, in the salesOrderItemEntity array, there should be a 'parent_item_id' attribute. 
Probably you want the configurable item only(that's where the price is) and want to filter out the child products while still allowing 'normal' simple products through.

```
if ($i['product_type'] == 'configurable' || ($i['product_type'] == 'simple' && $i['parent_item_id'] == null)){
  // insert info into your ERP or do something with the product
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for mage 1.9.x
Do what @Upperface wrote but with the  correct complex type name `salesOrderItemEntity`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                    schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="parent_item_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91221/33284

Answer (score 0):

make sure You use correct URL otherwise you can't see parent_item_id.

http://storeurl/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1